# Grid.MVC is raising an error when doing column filtering "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'hasAttribute'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, grid.mvc

I have installed the Grid.MVC http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/ inside my asp.net mvc5 web application. but now when i click on the filter icon beside a column i will get the following exception:-

```
> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 2416 in
> http://localhost:55951/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js
> 
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
> or method 'hasAttribute'
```

here is the code that will raise the exception inside the gridmvc.min.js file:-

```
function(t,i){var o=n(this).attr("data-type")||"",r=t.getFilterWidgetForType(o),u,h,e,c;if(r==null)return!1;if(this.hasAttribute("data-rendered"))return u=t.openMenuOnClick.call(this,t
```

so can anyone adivce on this please?

**EDIT**

i commented the code which is causing the error inside the script file,

```
 //if (this.hasAttribute("data-rendered")) {
      //  var or = self.openMenuOnClick.call(this, self);
      //   self.setupPopupInitialPosition($(this));
      //    if (!or && typeof (widget.onShow) != 'undefined')
      //        widget.onShow();
      //  return or;
      //  }
```

And now the filter box will be shown, but if i select any thing inside the type drop down the same filter box will be shown as follow:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you try using the full unminified version of gridmvc.js and see  if that either fixes it, or gives you more readbale code to work with?

Comment: @Rhumborl thanks for the reply. i try referencing the gridmvc.js  instead of the min version, but i got exactly the same exception .. can you adivce ?

Comment: @Rhumborl can you please check my edit to the original question ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue in only in IE browser. Please check IE browser compatibility mode it should be "Edge".
Also add 'meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"' in head tag.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> in Head tag of _layout.cshtml page. It will started working after adding this .